# jquery send 2 values from radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I been working on this for more of 8 hours trying different scripts Like: if/else, creating 2 names and values, creating "hidden" input with the name and values, create JavaScript but the jQuery brake, here is what I have thanks to @Mood http://jsfiddle.net/LZ5Uz/4/ : Now my first variable I need to post is "amount" (I have that one) but I need to send "recurring" from the same radio checked. Example:

```
   <input name="amount" id="result" type="hidden" />//Here I will send the variable "amount"
```

Now for the variable "recurring" I was trying:

```
   <input id="q" type="radio" name="presets,recurring" class="q" value="12,Quarterly" />Quarterly
   <labels id="choice_q" class="q"></label> //JQuery break
```

Try:

```
   $('input:radio[name="presets"]').change(
function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'monthly') {
       
    }
});
```

I am a noob on this... The variable and value I need to send is: (variable-->) name="recurring" (value -->) first radio is checked = "monthly" second radio checked = "quarterly" third radio checked = "year"

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: It would be easier to just know your requirements and then do it all for you...

Comment: By the demo "amount"=$ and "recurring"=(monthly,quarterly,year) I will post to another page.

Comment: `recurring` is another hidden element ????????

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rynhe/LZ5Uz/5/)...

Comment: Requirements: Enter amount that amount divided by 3,12,36 show by side of the radio button, choose radio and the amount in the radio show in the bottom text box and the same time give the value to the variable "recurring". so when I submit will be amount and recurring status.

Comment: yes recurring hidden element

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZ5Uz/7/)

**Description**

To solve the above problem I used **[knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/)** the reason is this is meant for this type of UI (UX). jQuery isn't meant for this type of design.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input id="amount" type="number" data-bind="value: Amount" />
</div>
<div>
    <input id="m" type="radio" name="presets" value="0" data-bind="checked: RecurringOption, value: Option1" />
    <label for="m" id="choice_m" data-bind="text: Option1"></label>
    <input id="q" type="radio" name="presets" value="1" data-bind="checked: RecurringOption, value: Option2" />
    <label for="q" id="choice_q" data-bind="text: Option2"></label>
    <input id="y" type="radio" name="presets" value="2" data-bind="checked: RecurringOption, value: Option3" />
    <label for="y" id="choice_y" data-bind="text: Option3"></label>
</div>
<input id="result" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
<input id="recurringOption" type="hidden" data-bind="value: RecurringOption" />
```

**JS**

```
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.Amount = ko.observable(50);
    this.RecurringOption = ko.observable();
    this.Option1 = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.Amount() != null) return (parseFloat(self.Amount(), 10) / parseFloat(36, 10)).toFixed(2);

        return 0;
    }, self);
    this.Option2 = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.Amount() != null) return (parseFloat(self.Amount(), 10) / parseFloat(12, 10)).toFixed(2);

        return 0;
    }, self);
    this.Option3 = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.Amount() != null) return (parseFloat(self.Amount(), 10) / parseFloat(3, 10)).toFixed(2);

        return 0;
    }, self);
}

$(function () {
    // Activates knockout.js
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

    $("input[name='presets']").change(function () {
        var id = $("input:checked").attr("id");
        $("#result").val($('#' +id).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: This code is good but I not understand something here: 'code' <input id="m" type="radio" name="presets" value="0" data-bind="checked: RecurringOption, value: Option1" />
    <label for="m" id="choice_m" data-bind="text: Option1"></label> :

Comment: So i cant change to (monthly...) because the script give to this value a number 'code' (this.Option1 = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.Amount() != null) return (parseFloat(self.Amount(), 10) / parseFloat(36, 10)).toFixed(2);) how I can send the recurring variable when all the variables are numbers?

Comment: @user1819551 thats easy you do this.Option1() to get the value